# How to specify input and output binding using azure resource manager

Tags: azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-automation, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm looking for automation in deployment using azure resource manager.
I'm looking for how to create input and output binding to the azure functions, using Azure resource manager.
How to do it

Answer (score 0):

Bindings are defined as part of the code package that is uploaded to the app. Today ARM can be used to create the resource, but not to create or upload the app code. You can point to previously updated code in a storage account, but for publishing activities you should look towards other related technologies like Azure DevOps to deploy code / define bindings as part of an automated pipeline.